EU 100ml restriction back in place with 1. September 2024
I was traveling from Helsinki airport and they have the new type of scanner for checking your on person luggage. It is said these can detect all kinds of liquids and therefore allow up to 2l of liquids to be carried on person instead of the max 100ml which where in place before.
Entering with bigger containers worked great and it was an overall nice experience, however everywhere were signs saying that this 2l limit will be reduced back to 100ml on 1. September 2024. Since I was wondering why this downgrade is happening I started to research but found no explanation/source. Only that it is related to EU regulation and hints that this is temporary, but with no given end date.
So my Question is why is this better limitation dropped? I guess its not the airport shop lobby. Does anyone know the reasoning or any sources on this?
